# Going through tables and replacing IDs resulting from duplicates in dimension table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates, duplicate-data

I have a dimension Users table that unfortunately has a bunch of duplicate records. See screenshot.  [image: Duplicate records.]

I have thousands of users and  5 tables referencing the duplicates.  I want to delete records with "bad" `UserID`s.  I want to go through the 5 dependencies and update bad `UserId`s with "good" (circled in red).

What would be a good approach to this?

**Here's what I did to get the above screenshot...**

```
SELECT UserID
    ,userIds.FirstName
    ,userIds.LastName
    ,dupTable.Email
    ,dupTable.Username
    ,dupTable.DupCount
FROM dbo.DimUsers AS userIds
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT FirstName
        ,LastName
        ,Email
        ,UserName
        ,DupCount
    FROM
        (SELECT FirstName
            ,LastName
            ,UserName
            ,Email
            ,COUNT(*) AS DupCount -- we're finding duplications by matches on FirstName,
                                    -- last name, UserName AND Email.  All four fields must match
                                    -- to find a dupe.  More confidence from this.
        FROM dbo.DimUsers
        GROUP BY FirstName
            ,LastName
            ,UserName
            ,Email
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS userTable -- any count more than 1 is a dupe
        WHERE LastName NOT LIKE 'NULL' -- exclude entries with literally NULL names
            AND FirstName NOT LIKE 'NULL'
        )AS dupTable
ON dupTable.FirstName = userIds.FirstName -- to get the userIds of dupes, we LEFT JOIN the original table
    AND dupTable.LastName = userIds.LastName -- on four fields to increase our confidence
    AND dupTable.Email = userIds.Email
    AND dupTable.Username = userIds.Username
WHERE DupCount IS NOT NULL -- ignore NULL dupcounts, these are not dupes
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work, created for 1 dependency table but you can use the same logic to update other 4 tables.

```
update t
set UserID = MinUserID.UserID
from
  DimUsersChild1 t
  inner join DimUsers on DimUsers.UserID = t.UserID
  inner join (
              select min(UserID) UserID, FirstName, LastName, UserName, Email
              from DimUsers
              group by
                FirstName, LastName, UserName, Email
              ) MinUserID on 
                          MinUserID.FirstName = DimUsers.FirstName and
                          MinUserID.LastName = DimUsers.LastName and
                          MinUserID.UserName = DimUsers.UserName and
                          MinUserID.Email = DimUsers.Email

select * from DimUsersChild1;

delete t1
from
  DimUsers t
  inner join DimUsers t1 on t1.FirstName = t.FirstName and
                            t1.LastName = t.LastName and
                            t1.UserName = t.UserName and
                            t1.Email = t.Email
where
t.UserID < t1.UserID


select * from DimUsers;
```

Here is a [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88b1c/1)